# How to store a matrix-valued time-series in R?

Tags: r, matrix, time-series

I'm wondering what's the best option to store (and process) a multivariate (in particular matrixvalued) time-series in R.

I have a large data frame which stores all the data as well as the time variable (in this case named `year`, as a column.)

Here's what I could think of, but both options have their disadvantages:

1. A list of dataframes, e.g. via `my.list[[i]] <- my.df[,year==i]`, looping over `i=2008:2011`. However, I don't know how to extract, e.g. the univariate series of the entry in the upper left corner of all these list entries.
2. As a `ts` object, but this would require transforming the matrix for a given year into a row vector, which might be a bit unwieldy to manipulate.

Are there other, better ways to store a time series of matrices (or even data frames)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do want the [zoo](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=zoo) or [xts](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=zoo) packages which have a million examples here and on the web, plus *a lot* of excellent documentation starting from the package vignettes.

Both [zoo](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=zoo) and [xts](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=zoo) 
essentially wrap a single index column of dates or datetimes around a (numeric) matrix of values.  You can still do all you can otherwise do with a matrix, plus better / smarter indexing and merging and subsetting etc pp.

Look for example here under a query `[r] zoo xts` in the search box above.  This (currently) gets me 509 results many of which will be worked examples.

Comment: Are there any specific advantages of using one over the other?

Comment: Well zoo is a bit more general ('ordered objects') and allows ties (but warns). And xts extends it, but uses only time or date.  These days I often start with the latter.  The plot methods differ.